# Query in join-table for N:M associations in Node JS and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a classical many-to-many relationship for users which own assets: assets can be transfered to other users during their life so a window time is recorded in the AssetUser "through table",
adding STARTDATE and ENDDATE attributes.

**User Table**

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
ID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
},
FIRSTNAME: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
LASTNAME: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
}},{ timestamps: false }});
```

**Asset Table**

```
const Asset = sequelize.define('Asset', {
ID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
},
DESCRIPTION: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
}},{ timestamps: false }});
```

**AssetUser Join Table**

```
const AssetUser = sequelize.define('AssetUser', {
id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false
},
UserID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'ID'
    }
},
AssetID: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    references: {
        model: Asset,
        key: 'ID'
    }
},
STARTDATE: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
},
ENDDATE: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: true,
    defaultValue: null
}},{ timestamps: false });
```

The models are created here:

```
User.belongsToMany(Asset, { through: { model: AssetUser, unique: false }, uniqueKey: 'id' });
Asset.belongsToMany(User, { through: { model: AssetUser, unique: false }, uniqueKey: 'id' });
```

My problem is that I want to query and find all the results where one asset, owned by one user, during a restricted period. I am not able to query the join-table but only User and Assets tables.
How can I add a "where" condition for the AssetUser table inside my query? How should I insert a STARTDATE and/or ENDDATE condition below?

```
Asset.findAll({
where: {
    DESCRIPTION: 'Personal computer'
},
include: {
    model: User,
    where: {
        FIRSTNAME: 'Marcello'
    }
}});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
Asset.findAll({ where: {     DESCRIPTION: 'Personal computer' }, include: {     model: User, through: {     where: {         FIRSTNAME: 'Marcello'     } } }});
```